# disable enter key on page, but NOT in textarea

Tags: javascript, forms

Found this script:

```
function stopRKey(evt) {
  var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
  var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null);
  if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type=="text"))  {return false;}
}

document.onkeypress = stopRKey;
```

Only issue, it also stops enter key being used in textarea. Which is a hassle.

I have toyed with using:

`onkeypress="return handleEnter(this, event)"`

But our forms are extremely complex, and I am looking for a cleaner way of doing things.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to check the [`nodeName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.nodeName) or [`tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.tagName) of the event target here, like this:

```
if (evt.keyCode == 13 && node.nodeName != "TEXTAREA") { return false; }
```

---

I noticed after this was accepted that you are already using jQuery, you can just replace all your code above with this:

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
  if(e.which == 13 && e.target.nodeName != "TEXTAREA") return false;
});
```

Comment: do we amend that code as is, or do we need to change nodeName ?

Comment: @422 - this is meant to replace the `if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type=="text"))  {return false;}` line of code...this way it returns `false` is it's enter and it's NOT a `<textarea>` you're in.

Comment: Yep, he's right. Basically what I said except use `.nodeName` instead of `.type`. Damn.

Comment: @422 - welcome, there's also a much easier jQuery solution since you're already including it, added it to the answer.

Comment: Tried:
<pre><!--disable enter key ver 2-->
<script type="text/javascript">
function stopRKey(evt) {
  var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
  var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null);
  $(document).keypress(e) {
  if(e.which == 13 && e.target.nodeName != "TEXTAREA") return false;
});
}
document.onkeypress = stopRKey;
</script> 
<!--//disable enter key ver 2--></pre>
But isnt working, have i cocked something up ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just change this line

```
if (evt.keyCode == 13 && node.type == "text") {
  return false;
}
```

to

```
if (evt.keyCode == 13 && node.type != "TEXTAREA") {
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Nope, doesnt work for us. Still tries to submit form. Will keep playing with it, as this seems cleanest way of achieveing what we want to do

Comment: Sorry should be `.nodeName`.  (But @Nick Craver found that bug, not me.)

Answer (score 1):

If you use jquery (highly recommended) then this will automatically add the function to allow use of the enter key:

```
$("textarea").focus(function () { 
     $(this).keypress(handleEnter);
});
```

Comment: We do use jquery, do we just use your code within normal script tags ?