# Prevent user hitting Enter except Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a fairly complex form which has multiple stages with many different text fields and text areas. The environment it is used within used barcodes which hit enter by default, and that is by choice as they scan a multitude of products using them so turning the enter function off has become a no-go.

I am using a form wizard script which handles client-side validation during the input stage. This script is interrupted by the enter key being hit during filling out the form and refuses to submit until the page is refreshed.

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="btn green button-submit">Submit <i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i></a>
```

I have the following code which works to prevent enter on the form and allows the form to submit when the link above is clicked.

```
$(window).keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

However this prevents enter being used within textarea. I did a bit of research and tried using the `is()` operator from jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).keydown(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13 && !event.is("textarea")) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

This doesn't work, it fails to prevent the enter key in inputs and stalls the form from submitting as it did prior.

Finally this is the javascript that handles submitting the form if validation passes on the form

```
$('#form_wizard_1 .button-submit').click(function () {
    // Can put more onsubmit processing here
    document.getElementById('submit_form').submit();
}).hide();
```

---

Can anyone suggest how I can prevent the enter key on all inputs EXCEPT for textareas. I don't pretend to be a JavaScript developer, although I am trying to learn as I go. The following are articles I have read and either attempted to adapt code or failed to understand how it would apply to me in the correct manner:

[Prevent users from submitting a form by hitting Enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-form-by-hitting-enter)

[Prevent Users from submitting form by hitting enter #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923683/prevent-users-from-submitting-form-by-hitting-enter-2)

[disable enter key on page, but NOT in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221464/disable-enter-key-on-page-but-not-in-textarea)

---

*In regards to the last link, I need a global resolution that automatically prevents it on all textareas that may exist within the form.

As always, thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Have you tried using `!$(event.target).is("textarea")`

Comment: I'm not completely sure what *script* you're using and how is it getting *interrupted*...

Comment: I was unaware that this existed through my research, could you post this as a proper reply so I can upvote and accept it, this worked EXACTLY as intended.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### JavaScript

Use [KeyboardEvent.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) and [Element.matches(selectors)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)

```js
document.querySelector("#myForm").addEventListener("keydown", (evt) => {
  if (evt.key === "Enter" && !evt.target.matches("textarea")) {
    evt.preventDefault(); // Don't trigger form submit
    console.log("ENTER-KEY PREVENTED ON NON-TEXTAREA ELEMENTS");
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input name="inp" placeholder="Click here and hit Enter" type="text">
  <textarea name="txa" placeholder="Click here and hit Enter"></textarea>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

#### jQuery

Use `!$(event.target).is("textarea")`
Also use `Event.key`, or use `Event.which` (instead of `Event.keyCode`; jQuery normalizes it for cross-browser)

```js
jQuery(function($) { // DOM ready

  $('form').on('keydown', function(ev) {
    if (ev.key === "Enter" && !$(ev.target).is('textarea')) {
      ev.preventDefault(); // Don't trigger form submit
      console.log("ENTER-KEY PREVENTED ON NON-TEXTAREA ELEMENTS");
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="inp" placeholder="Click here and hit Enter" type="text">
  <textarea name="txa" placeholder="Click here and hit Enter"></textarea>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did a quick search - however to verify, the console.log wont cause issues in a browser that doesn't support those debugging features (aka like FireBug or chromes built-in debugging)

Comment: If you stop the bubbeling (via `evt.stopPropagation();`) instead, you could bind the event listener directly to the textarea, making the `.match` check obsolete and having overall fewer event calls

Comment: @LukasKroess  `evt.stopPropagation()` should (almost) never be used. Unless for debugging or if you really, really know what you're doing. At any time and app and its third party scripts should be notified about events happening in their environment.